# JavaScript onClick in script tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

my code (mini-calculator app): (html/js)

```
<input class="value" type="text" id="first" />
<input class="value" type="text" id="second" />
<input class="value" type="text" id="result" />
<input class="button" type="button" value="+" id="plus" />

window.onLoad = function motor()
{
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
    
    function updateResult(act)
    {
        var first = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
        var second = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
        if (isNaN(first)) first = 0;
        if (isNaN(second)) second = 0;

        if (act == '+') {
            document.getElementById("result").value = first + second;
        }
    }
    plus.onClick = updateResult('+');
}
```

which doesn't work. I need an onClick action when button "id" is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result of the function call to the onclick event.  You are not assigning a reference to the function.

Also, the click event name uses a *lower* case c.

```
plus.onclick = function(){updateResult('+');};
```

Comment: I missed the fact you had a capital C. The event is case sensitive. I went to fix it by @svidgen already did!

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `plus` object's `onClick` property to a function not the result of calling `updateResult()` (which is undefined).  One way to achieve this is to have `updateResult()` return a function:

```
window.onLoad = function motor()
{
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");

    function updateResult(act)
    {
        return function(){
            var first = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
            var second = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
            if (isNaN(first)) first = 0;
            if (isNaN(second)) second = 0;

            if (act == '+') {
                document.getElementById("result").value = first + second;
            }
        };
    }
    plus.onclick = updateResult('+');
}
```

Comment: It is onclick :) You had same issue as my post!

Comment: Thanks for fixing it - typically I wouldn't even assign handlers in this was so I just focused on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
//JS is case-sensitive, the correct property name is `onload` not onLoad
window.onload = function motor()
[...]
    //onclick not onClick
    plus.onclick = function() {
      //you need to assign a function to execute on `onclick` instead of
      //the return value of calling it with () which you were doing previously
      updateResult('+');
    };
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JMCK9/1/)

Also, consider using a code quality analysis tool such as [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). Even though it may not catch these mistypes as it is "valid" to create new properties on these objects, It should help you in the future. Also, if you're in doubt about how to use a function or property or its proper spelling/syntax, you can check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). For example, [`window.onload` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for onload, just call the event click. Here is the code:

```js
document.getElementById("plus").onclick = function() {updateResult();};
    
    function updateResult()
    {
        var first = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
        var second = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
        if (isNaN(first)) first = 0;
        if (isNaN(second)) second = 0;

        document.getElementById("result").value = first + second;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input class="value" type="text" id="first" />
    <input class="value" type="text" id="second" />
    <input class="value" type="text" id="result" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="+" id="plus" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `onclick`, not `onClick`.

Please make sure the case is correct.